# Подключение библиотеки SFML

Tags: c++, sfml

Добрый день уважаемые пользователи,столкнулся с такой **проблемой:**

Подключил библиотеку **SFML** к **visual studio 2019** (Все делал строго по инструкции как для 32 битной системы так и для 64 битной)

При компиляции программы выдается следующая **ошибка:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

****100 раз перепроверял,все эти файлики,которые не может обнаружить система,в папке с проектом есть!Все 11 файлов!И находятся они в нужном месте.***

Подскажите пожалуйста,в чем может быть ошибка?

**P.S** *4* библиотеки в конфигурации **Debug** в пункте

Компоновщик **->** Ввод тоже подключил!

Comment: Точно при компиляции? Запускаете как? Библиотека в той же директории, откуда запускаете?

Comment: @dIm0n Да при компиляции,запускаю нажатием клавиши f5.

Comment: Ну вы говорите при компиляции, а в ошибке сказано "не удалось продолжить **выполнение кода**". Попробуйте запустить получившийся exe файл вручную, удостоверившись, что в той же директории есть файл `sfml-graphics-d-2.dll`

Comment: Студия создает две директории в проекте для релиза и дебага. В них соответсвующие сборки. Дллки должны быть в директории для соотвествующей сборки рядом с эксешником

Answer (score 0):

> Студия создает две директории в проекте для релиза и дебага. В них соответсвующие сборки. Дллки должны быть в директории для соотвествующей сборки рядом с эксешником
>
> — [EOF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/361068/eof)